# “Tengo (el) cabello largo”

Tags: adjetivos, artículos

Se me ha planteado una duda (la plantea un hablante no nativo de español, y me la planteo yo también) con respecto al uso opcional del artículo en frases como las siguientes:

- Tengo cabello largo.
- Tengo el cabello largo.
- Tengo el cabello sucio.
- Tengo nariz grande.
- Tengo la nariz grande.
- Tengo la nariz tapada.

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna diferencia semántica (por muy sutil que sea) entre las frases con y sin artículo.

Mi sensación, forzando un poco el asunto, es que las frases sin artículo sugieren una situación permanente (no inmutable, pero considerada como más o menos parte de la imagen personal propia del sujeto), mientras que las frases con artículo tienden a connotar un estado contingente. ¿Es esto así o sólo me lo parece a mí?

Una pista que podría seguirse es: qué ocurre si uno parafrasea los ejemplos anteriores cambiando la idea de posesión por un predicado como "Mi cabello es largo" o "Mi nariz está tapada".

Answer (score 4):

Voy a ensayar una teoría:

1. Para características permanentes, se puede usar o no el artículo definido. Me parece que la ausencia de artículo -- si bien de uso general -- es típica de descripciones crudas, como por ejemplo las que hace la policía:

   - Tiene **(el)** cabello rubio.
   - Tiene **(los)** ojos castaños.
   - Tiene **(la)** nariz respingada.
   - Tiene **(las)** piernas largas.
   - Tiene **(el)** cuerpo delgado.
2. Para características permanentes, también se puede usar el artículo indefinido. Se me ocurre que en general se usa para describir a personas hasta ahora desconocidas. Es mucho menos común que (1) y puede sonar algo poético:

   - Tiene **un** cuerpo esbelto, **unos** ojos color de cielo y **un** cabello de sirena.
3. Para características temporarias, se debe usar el artículo definido:

   - Tiene **el** cabello sucio.
   - Tiene **los** ojos llorosos.
   - Tiene **la** nariz tapada.
   - Tiene **las** piernas entumecidas.
   - Tiene **el** cuerpo debilitado.

Comment: Creo que has acertado.  Voy a plantear una respuesta que creo que concuerda con la tuya -- pero con una presentación un poquito diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Si una mujer se describe para que alguien la reconozca en la terminal de autobús o la estación de tren, dice

- Tengo cabello largo y lacio.

Si está planeando el día con su hermana, y le comenta que quiere ir a recortarse el pelo, dice

- Quiero sacar cita en el salón de belleza.  Tengo el cabello muy largo y maltratado.

Si va a encontrarse en la terminal con una amiga a la que no ha visto desde hace tiempo, entonces diría "Tengo el cabello muy largo ahora".  Es decir, "lo tengo largo" = "lo uso largo".

En inglés hay una diferencia parecida, entre "I have long hair" (para verse con alguien en la terminal), y "My hair is getting long" (para sacar cita para el recorte de pelo).